# Why has my camera button/icon disappeared?

Tags: camera

You know that camera icon that shows up in the right-hand side of the main viewer? Well, it disappeared. I know I can toggle with CTRL-0 but I would *really* like to know why this happened and what I can do to get it back.

I have looked throughout as many options as I can locate, but no dice.

Here is my viewer:
[image]

As you will note, there is no camera button on the right side.

Also: Yes. I have restarted. Would not have posted here without taking a number of steps. No effect. It's like I've toggled something.

Comment: Still looking for what button might bring it back, if you haven't put too much work into your scene you can always start a new file and it will be back.

Comment: No luck there. I've done a ton of work. And the camera hotkey is behaving _all kinds of squirrelly_ now and I have no idea. I appear to be locked in some kind of camera mode even though no such camera is selected.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Have you tried saving the scene and restarting blender

Comment: Updated thread.

Comment: Do you mean the [outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html?highlight=outliner)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Gizmos visibility

You have somehow disabled the gizmos visibility, you can simply re-enable it by pressing the button in the bar:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Still enough of a noob not to see that.